# Questions after overwriting Vista with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista

I recently overwrote Vista with Windows 7. However, I'm still offered the option the dual boot when I start up my computer. I've removed the windows.old file, and I'm wondering now what I need to do to remove Vista. I have EasyBCD to remove the Vista entry from the boot menu, but I don't think that's all I need to do. If the dual boot option is there, then for some reason is Vista on my computer and if so how do I remove it?

P.S. I already removed the windows.old folder that was created.

Note that there is no separate partition for Vista.  It's all on one drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you did not reformat your hard drive, then there is probably still an entry in the master boot record pointing to the Vista instance, even though technically they are in the same location (If i'm following your question properly).

There is an outside change that you still Vista on your machine, if you created a second partition on your hard drive and installed Windows 7 there. You would be able to see this by going into the Computer Management section, selecting the "Disk Management" option, and viewing the partitions on the disk. If there was an extra partition there, aside from your System Reserved and C: sections.

When all is said and done, go ahead and use EasyBCD to remove the additional boot entry, or if you haven't done much to the system and have everything backed up, do the install again, but make sure to delete all partitions during the initial install process and do a reformat to make sure everything is gone.

Comment: Well I have 3 partitions. The Data drive (logical parition) with nothing on it, and apparently 2 primary paritions. One has no name, and the other is my Windows7. Is it safe to say that Vista is not on my machine? I don't believe I created a second partition, because when it asked me where to install Win7, I just chose the partition where Vista was currently installed. Also, should I delete the one that is blank? I have no idea what it is. The only info it gives is that it is 10.74 GB and is a primary partition ( the other partition being my main one with Win7)

Comment: Hmm, its difficult for me to say. Does the partition with no name have a drive letter assigned to it? If not, you should be able to assign a drive letter to it and then you can look around and see if it has your Vista files.